# How to get the handle of a MainMenu object in Compact Framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework, pinvoke, handle

Using the compact framework (ie managed code), how can I get the handle to a MainMenu object?

(P/Invoking is fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/13c61782-ff68-40ee-81a0-58b0acaca1f9